# how to find the current sensing resistor value for linear mosfet?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I am new to this field, that's why i am trying to find the value of current sensing resistor for monitoring the drain current of MOSEFT which is used in this picture. as an electronic load, the current of device under test should be controlled and tracked based on reference. how can i calculate the value of this sense resistor? and also need to have a view for selecting the amplifiers?!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The maximum resistor value will be determined by the required *compliance* of the current sink- that is the minimum voltage * current at which the sink can be expected to work. If we assume the MOSFET will work well down to (say) 1 volt even at the highest temperature anticipated, then the current sink will work down to Rsense * I + 1V. So if you want it to sink 1A and work down to 1.8V then the sense resistor must be no higher value than 0.8 ohms.

The minimum resistor value will be determined by the required accuracy and op-amp characteristics. For example, if a 2mA error is acceptable and the op-amp has a 1mV Vos over temperature, then the resistor can be no smaller than 0.5 ohms.

Within that range you will probably be constrained by standard values (and combinations thereof).

The resistor maximum power dissipation can easily be calculated from the maximum current - P = I^2R. It's a good idea to derate the resistor (specify one with higher capability than strictly required) to improve the accuracy.

This circuit is prone to instability so you should pick a single supply op-amp that has high capacitive drive capability and/or add compensation.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation really depends on wattage of the resistor to be selected. The higher the resistance the greater accuracy that can be achieved especially at low current values. The drawback of higher resistance is more heat at high current values. For example at the maximum current of 4A and a resistor of 1ohm the wattage is 16W. That is a lot of heat to dissipate. Most likely the value you settle on will be much less than an ohm. Side note, consider placing many identical resistors in parallel to share the load.

As far as the Opamps go the only real thing to consider is to make sure that they are capable of going down to ground on the output when using then with a singe supply.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 1 ohm resister  you waste 16watt like has been said before .But its power thats going into the single linear FET so the total heating is the same .70Volts  at 4 amp means 280watts which will mean LOTs of mosfets in paralell OR in a series cascode setup .So your proposed 1 ohm resistor will be multiple resistors in paralell ,maybe 8 8ohm resisters .NOW there is a horrible snag ! New mosfets in linear mode have to be derated significantly .You can use expensive lateral FETs or use higher than necessary VDS devices .say 500V and use old generation if you can,and run the fets in series .Finaly heed the warnings about stability from spehro .I have seen this circuit in 1992 and watched in mirth as people in a world leading company wrestled with it never getting it totaly right.